# Trouble Installing ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 20.04 with arm64/x86_64 Architecture

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, installation, troubleshooting

I've been encountering an issue while attempting to install ROS 2 Humble on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. My machine supports both arm64 and x86_64 architectures. Despite following the official installation instructions closely, I run into the "unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop" error every time I try to execute the installation command.

Here are the steps I've followed based on the instructions from the ROS.org page for Humble:

**1. Added the ROS 2 repository and keyring as follows:**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y

sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
```

**2. Updated and upgraded my package lists:**

```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
```

**3. Attempted to install ROS 2 Humble packages:**

```
   sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop
```

However, this results in the "unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop" error.

Interestingly, I came across a similar issue on ROS Answers where a user encountered package location errors due to their system running on an ARMhf platform. However, after checking my system using `dpkg --print-architecture` and `lscpu`, I confirmed that my system is on `arm64` and `x86_64`, which should be compatible with ROS 2 Humble according to REP 2000.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has faced a similar issue or could offer guidance on resolving this error. Could this problem be related to my prior attempts to uninstall ROS 2 Foxy and clean my system? Or is there something else I'm missing in the setup process for ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 20.04?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal case, ROS2 Humble binary installation is available in Ubuntu 22.04 version, unless you have built a separate container environment.

[image]

```
**Installation**
Options for installing ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill:

Binary packages
Binaries are only created for the Tier 1 operating systems listed in REP-2000. Given the nature of Rolling, this list may be updated at any time. If you are not running any of the following operating systems you may need to build from source or use a container solution to run ROS 2 on your platform.

We provide ROS 2 binary packages for the following platforms:

Ubuntu Linux - Jammy Jellyfish (22.04)

Debian packages (recommended)

“fat” archive

RHEL 8

RPM packages (recommended)

“fat” archive

Windows (VS 2019)
```

Or you could try Source Install
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html
[image]

```
Ubuntu (source)
Table of Contents

System requirements

System setup

Set locale

Add the ROS 2 apt repository

Install development tools and ROS tools

Get ROS 2 code

Install dependencies using rosdep

Install additional DDS implementations (optional)

Build the code in the workspace

Environment setup

Source the setup script

Try some examples

Next steps after installing

Using the ROS 1 bridge

Additional RMW implementations (optional)

Alternate compilers

Clang

Stay up to date

Troubleshooting

Uninstall

System requirements
The current Debian-based target platforms for Humble Hawksbill are:

Tier 1: Ubuntu Linux - Jammy (22.04) 64-bit

Tier 3: Ubuntu Linux - Focal (20.04) 64-bit

Tier 3: Debian Linux - Bullseye (11) 64-bit
```

Comment: I do, however, use Ubuntu 20.04. In any case, as stated in the documents, Ubuntu 20.04 is also supported. But the issue persists, and it truly puzzles me.

Comment: I don't know exactly what your intentions are, but I recommend you try the source install.
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html

Comment: Please copy and paste the text and not a screenshot. Images are not text searchable.

Comment: Thanks, added the text.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I decided to continue with Ubuntu 22.04, it works seamlessly with it.